# 100 ohms resistor overheating

Tags: led, resistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjI1ru.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This simple circuit is causing to the resistor to overheat. How do I fix this?

Comment: Add more of yourself or decrease power supply.

Comment: what do you mean by `overheating`? ... how warm were you expecting it to get? ... how warm does it get?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat it took me a while to get the joke. LOL.

Comment: In this circuit, do you know how much current is flowing? I would guess it is something like 60 or 70 mA. If you have a volt meter, you could just turn it on and measure the voltage across the 100 ohm resistor.

Comment: You are aware that you're exceeding the LED's maximum current ratings by at least a factor of two, yes?

Answer (score 4):

> **How do I fix this?**

Add more LEDs in series.

---

The proper answer is to read the datasheet for the LEDs and design your circuit appropriately. You should calculate the required power dissipation in your resistor.

The LTL-307EE you show in your circuit has a forward voltage of 2V, so your resistor has to drop 8V. Your current at 100 ohms is 80 mA (the LTL-307EE is only rated 20mA and will die soon at 80mA). The power dissipated in the resistor is 640 mW which is too high for a small resistor rated at 125 mW.

So by doing the calculations for your real LED, you might find you need a higher power resistor (e.g. a 10 watt resistor instead of a 1/8th watt resistor). You might choose a resistor with a higher resistance to reduce the current (and potentially extend the life of the LEDs)

[image: Resistors of varying wattage]

Adding more LEDs in series means the resistor has to work less hard.

Using a 5V power supply would be another option.

Comment: I doubt the OP used correct part numbers for the LED's. The reason I say that is that they are both the same part number but one is labelled red and the other is labelled green. Probably the green LED has a bit higher forward voltage than the red. And probably both have high forward voltage since they are being driven way over 20 mA (which, no matter the part number, is probably the max current).

Comment: @mkeith: I agree. Which is why I mentioned *"So by doing the calculations for your **real** LED  ..."* but maybe I could have made it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Three things come to mind.

1. Use a larger resistor. Probably the 100 ohm resistor has 6 or 7 volts across it which is too much current for your LED's probably anyway. They probably want about 20 mA at most. You can try 220 ohms, or 470 or even 1000 ohms. This will make the light dimmer.
2. Use a lower voltage instead of 12 volts. If that is possible in your case. This will also make the light dimmer.
3. Use more LED's in series. This will make each individual LED dimmer but the total light, if you add it up, will not be less. And it will be more efficient, too.

You can also mix and match the above suggestions. Raise the resistor and lower the voltage and add another LED.

Comment: If you really want to keep 100 ohms and 12 volts with these two LED's, then the other option is to use a resistor with a higher power rating. It would be helpful if you could measure the voltage across the 100 ohm resistor while the circuit is on. But I would guess that you would want to use a 1 watt 100 ohm resistor. The resistor will still get hot. But if it is a 1 watt resistor it should be able to handle the heat.

Answer (score 1):

You don't just hook a circuit up and assume it is going to work.

You research the LEDs and find their forward voltages and currents.  If you meet that criteria the LEDs will light up.

Now you do KVL (Kirchoff's Voltage Law).  The sum of the voltages around a closed loop equals 0.

$$+ V_{CC} - V_{R_2} - V_{{LED}_{Green}} - V_{{LED}_{Red}} = 0 $$

You should have every thing to find out the voltage drop required to make the circuit work.  As in light up the LEDs.

$$ V_{R_2} = + V_{CC} - V_{{LED}_{Green}} - V_{{LED}_{Red}}$$

Plug in values and solve for \$V_{R_2}\$.  Now Ohm's Law.  Odds are that forward currents for the two LEDs may be different.  Pick the lowest.

$$R_2 =  \frac {V_{R_2}}{I_F} $$

Now find a resistor a little bit higher and the circuit will work.  Experiment to get it to the brightness you want.

Any other approach is trial and error.  It can work, but you could damage components and it is not engineering.

Resistance is futile, but the proper resistance does make things work!